# cant access from laravel docker container to the mariadb local server

Tags: laravel, docker, mariadb

I have a docker container with laravel project. I try access to the mariadb server in the this server (remote linux server). But I have an error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user2'@'185.180.230.129'.
I wrote the correct password and login to the database.
I wrote the host.docker.internal in env from to the DB_CONNECTION.
I wrote users in mariadb like 'root'@'localhost' or 'user2@'ip_server:port_app'
But I cant connect....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should try run this on your DB first (rename the USER & Password with yours).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also try to edit the `50-server.cnf` of MariaDB config to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Otherwise I'll guess you have some docker networking issue with allowing the two containers to communicate.